# Sort array after any element propery changes - Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am writing a [demo app](http://jsfiddle.net/GSvnh/5924/) and I am trying to implement sorting on every property change of any element in the array.I am using a computed property

```
this.sortedItems = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.allItems().sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.name() > b.name();
    });
}, this);
```

It sorts when I am changing all of the items, but when I change the name of one, it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because of name case-sensitivity. So just change 
return a.name() > b.name(); to 
return a.name().toUpperCase() > b.name().toUpperCase();